# Unable to generate ipa using Appollo

Tags: ipa, flutter-build

I am trying to build a flutter webview app in ios version. I used appollo for generating the ipa file, but it turns out it cannot build the ipa file and display errors.

I run command "appollo build start", choosing type 'ad-hoc' and wait for it to run, and
I got the following error message:

Ipa collection - IPA file not found - Error code 95
[Appollo](https://appollo.space/)

Here are my logs:

```
(Removed for shorter code)
----- Building IPA with Flutter -----
Archiving com.northbankclub.mobile...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 99L9TNDFH7
Running pod install... 698ms
Running Xcode build...
Xcode archive done. 58.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/xs/ypw_ztps3mg5wt2mtfymvvb40000gn/T/flutter_tools.8JQlkU/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir8mMpuE/temporary_xcresult_bundle
/* com.apple.actool.document.warnings */
/Users/appollo/Documents/app/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/(null)[2d][Icon-App-50x50@1x.png]: warning: The app icon set "AppIcon" has 6 unassigned children.
/Users/appollo/Documents/app/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/(null)[2d][Icon-App-50x50@1x.png]: warning: The app icon set "AppIcon" has 6 unassigned children.
/* com.apple.actool.document.notices */
/Users/appollo/Documents/app/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset/[][ipad][76x76][][][1x][][][]: notice: 76x76@1x app icons only apply to iPad apps targeting releases of iOS prior to 10.0.
/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
/Users/appollo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-crwpljrlpmylaoaeyrpgtwrpnsno/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png
/Users/appollo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-crwpljrlpmylaoaeyrpgtwrpnsno/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
/Users/appollo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-crwpljrlpmylaoaeyrpgtwrpnsno/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/Assets.car
/Users/appollo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-crwpljrlpmylaoaeyrpgtwrpnsno/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist
/Users/appollo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-crwpljrlpmylaoaeyrpgtwrpnsno/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-DAF5D85F83E67F121E2D5545.sh: line 2: /Users/appollo/Documents/app/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh: Permission denied
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Building targets in dependency order
note: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
note: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
Result bundle written to path:
/var/folders/xs/ypw_ztps3mg5wt2mtfymvvb40000gn/T/flutter_tools.8JQlkU/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir8mMpuE/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Encountered error while archiving for device.
----- Getting modified sources -----
IPA file not found
Build stop order received at 2023-06-12 08:00:20.058090+00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for raising this issue. This error was due to the zip format used to send the source code to the build machine not keeping the execution permission on the pod scripts.
It has now been fixed.

The Appollo team